# Imap connexion work in localhost but crash in server

Tags: php, crash, imap

I am working with a basic imap open function that allows me to get emails from inbox. The function works properly on my localhost (wamp) and on my previous server. 
We recently changed web server. Now, the function crashes the server at the time of the imap connection.

I looked through a phpinfo all that was related to the imap and I found no difference with the phpinfo of my localhost.

Here is the imap constructor, the function crash on the last line.

```
 public function __construct($mailbox, $username, $password, $encryption = false)
    {
        $enc = '';
        if ($encryption != null && isset($encryption) && $encryption == 'ssl') {
            $enc = '/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert';
        } elseif ($encryption != null && isset($encryption) && $encryption == 'tls') {
            $enc = '/imap/tls/novalidate-cert';
        }
        $this->mailbox = '{' . $mailbox . $enc . '}';
        $this->imap    = @imap_open($this->mailbox, $username, $password);
    }
```

And my phpinfo :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `@imap_open('{' + $this->mailbox + '}', $username, $password);` ?

Comment: This is the same unfortunately

Comment: Crashes how?  Have you checked your firewall rules?  Used a network debugging tool like scoot to see if you can make the connection from the server?

Comment: The page runs until the timeout and I have to restart the server. Where can I test this?

Comment: Well, hopefully you can get access to a shell so that you can try openssl s_client or socat; which are command line tools for connecting to servers.